# How to extract frames(or a perticular frame) from a YUV video using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, yuv

Here is the code for extracting frames from a `MP4` video. 
`ffmpeg -i above_marathon_250.mp4 images%03d.bmp` 
But the same code does not work for `YUV` format video.
Does anyone knows how it is possible to extract frame(s) from `YUV`format video?

Answer (score 10):

It's not working because yuv files have no header, so ffmpeg doesn't know what size/pixfmt the file is. You need to specify resolution and pixmt manually:

`ffmpeg -video_size 1920x1080 -r 25 -pixel_format yuv422p -i file.yuv output-%d.png`

And then adjust size/pixfmt to match your particular video.

[edit] I'd also suggest to post such questions on superuser in the future, this has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks @Ronald
Also, i am new in StackOverflow, so i need to know about superuser. i will do. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The command given in ffmpeg.org is

```
ffmpeg -i foo.avi -r 1 -s WxH -f image2 foo-%03d.jpeg
```

This will extract one video frame per second from the video and will output them in files named foo-001.jpeg, foo-002.jpeg, etc. Images will be rescaled to fit the new WxH values.

In your case you can modify the above command to

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile.yuv -r 1 -f image2 images%05d.png
```

where r is frame rate which should be set to 1, to extract single frame from yuv

Comment: setting `r=1`
ffmpeg -i inputfile.yuv -1 1 -f image2 images%05d.png 
It does not work.

Comment: r is already having a value 1 in the above command so use the command as it is

Comment: It does not create any image and this is the message on command line:

`[rawvideo @ 0x7fef6880da00] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video:rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, -4 kb/s):unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and'probesize' options above_marathon_250.yuv: could not find codec parameters
Input #0,rawvideo, from 'above_marathon_250.yuv':
  Duration:N/A,bitrate:n/a
    Stream #0:0:Video:rawvideo(I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, -4 kb/s, 25 tbr, 25 tbn,25 tbc
Output #0,image2,to'images%05d.png':
Output file #0 does not contain any stream`

Comment: Pl. find the below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659267/ffmpeg-10-04-could-not-find-codec-parameters where it is mentioned that                                     The files I was testing were in fact damaged. But if anyone faces this problem, setting -probesize and -analyzeduration to 100 and 10000000 for example might help.

Comment: can't see any positive result :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the video size `-video_size` and frame rate `-r` so use the following script:

```
ffmpeg.exe -video_size 720x576 -r 25 -ss 00:00:00 -i video_input_720x576_25.yuv -vframes 1 -q:v 1 frame_output_720x576_25.jpg
```

In case you want to specify input video format include `-pixel_format yuv420p` or any other format except `yuv420p`.