# FFMPEG: crop a video without losing the quality

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have mp4 video of `1920x1080`. I would like to crop the video to `480x270` **without quality loss**.

I am using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v "crop=480:270:200:200" -crf 23 output.mp4
```

I also tried:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v "crop=480:270:200:100" -c:a copy -qp 0 output.mp4
```

I used `-crf 23` and `-qp 0` for loseless video cropping, but after cropping video has lost quality.

Does anyone know how I can crop the video **without losing** the quality?

Comment: Please show the complete console output from your `ffmpeg` command.

Comment: here u can find the console output: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1r4pdgdmtj9ilnm/consol-output.rtf?dl=0

Thanks

Comment: You should edit your question to include the console output. You can crop during playback. Will that be an acceptable solution?

Comment: crop during the playback? what shell i add with this command for that?<br>
`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v "crop=480:270:200:100" -c:a copy  -qp 0 output.mp4`

Comment: There is no lossless crop for H.264, you are re-encoding the content. Hence, the quality loss.

Comment: @RomanR. is there any other way to crop video without loosing any quality?

Comment: You will have to re-encode the content. The only way to not lose quality is to use lossless as the new new encoding.

Comment: To crop, you need to re-encode. But you could get better quality by using `-crf 18` for example, instead of `-crf 23`.

Comment: I believe that some h264 can be cropped losslessly. For instance, if every frame is a keyframe, and the compression is done within independent areas. I have played with a filter that just copies the data from the cropped rectangle, while omitting other areas data. But on output on anything that had non-key frames had artifacts around the borders.

Answer (score 66):

**You can't perform any filtering without losing quality when encoding to a lossy format**, but you have some options.

## Crop with your player

A possible solution would be to crop during playback, so you don't even need to re-encode. It is also useful to preview a crop.

**This method will not create an output file. This will use your video player to crop while it is playing. See one of the other methods below if you want an output file.**

With `ffplay` and [crop filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop):

```
ffplay -vf "crop=480:270:200:100" input.mp4
```

With `vlc` (or `cvlc`):

```
vlc input.mp4 --crop=480x270+200+100
```

Or you could crop with the VLC GUI: Tools → Effects & Filters → Video Effects → Crop.

## Accept some quality loss (you may not even notice a difference)

Give it enough bits and you may not be able to tell there is a quality difference:

```
ffmpeg -i input -vf "crop=480:270:200:100" -c:v libx264 -crf 17 -c:a copy ouput.mp4
```

See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264 Video Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) for more info.

## Use a bitstream filter

The [h264_metadata](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-bitstream-filters.html#h264_005fmetadata) and [hevc_metadata](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-bitstream-filters.html#hevc_005fmetadata) bitstream filters can set crop dimensions without modifying the video itself.

**Note: Your player may not support this method.**

Example for H.264 video:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_metadata=crop_left=100:crop_right=20:crop_top=10:crop_bottom=10 output.mp4
```

- Sets the frame cropping offsets in the SPS. These values will replace the current ones if the stream is already cropped.
- These fields are set in pixels. Note that some sizes may not be representable if the chroma is subsampled or the stream is interlaced (see H.264 section 7.4.2.1.1).

## Use a lossless format

`ffmpeg` can encode with several lossless encoders: ffv1, huffyuv, ffvhuff, utvideo, libx264 (using [`-crf 0`](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#LosslessH.264) or `-qp 0`). The output will be lossless but the output file will be huge.

**Note: Your player may not support this method.**

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "crop=480:270:200:100" -c:v ffv1 -c:a copy output.mkv
```

or

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "crop=480:270:200:100" -c:v libx264 -crf 0 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

## If your input is MJPEG

[Stream copy the individual images with `ffmpeg`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-bitstream-filters.html#mjpeg2jpeg), crop them losslessly with `jpegtran`, then remux them with `ffmpeg`. This will result in no loss, but you will be restricted to the ancient MJPEG format.

Comment: In my mac i have ffmpeg installed already, i am not sure how i can use ffplay?

Comment: I used Homebrew.
as far i remember i followed these instructions: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/MacOSX

Thanks

Comment: yes i know, but i always get ffplay not found message: 

`Masuds-MacBook-Pro:golf masudrana$ cd selected
Masuds-MacBook-Pro:selected masudrana$ ffplay -vf "crop=480:270:200:100" golf.mp4
-bash: ffplay: command not found`

Comment: @MasudRana Maybe it didn't install or it is not in your `PATH`. I'm not familiar with OS X, so I can't recommend anything else. Try searching for the `ffplay` binary. Alternatively, get `ffplay` from http://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/.

Comment: ok i managed with windows and trying with ffplay.
your given command `ffplay -vf "crop=480:270:504:720" credits.mp4`
its giving me a warning: data is not aligned! this can lead to a speedloss.
`[swscaler @ 0000001cab897d20] Warning: data is not aligned! This can lead to a speedloss
 553.98 M-V:  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B`.  My original video is 1920x1080

Comment: can u please explain what is the process of doing it? i think ffplay is for previewing the cropping but not to crop really!!

Comment: @mrana The player is cropping during playback. It is not making a new video. Filtering requires re-encoding, and re-encoding (to a lossy format) will cause generational quality loss. So your options are to either crop during playback, crop and re-encode to a lossless format resulting in a huge file, or accepting some quality loss.

Comment: if i used VLC command in windows:<br>
`vlc input.mp4 --crop=480x270+200+100` <br> where the output file location and name? Can you please help me with this?

Comment: i used the following command:
`vlc input.mp4 --crop=480x500+290+720 out.mp4` but it gives me the following error:
`File reading failed:
VLC could not open the file "out.mp4" (Bad file descriptor).
Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'out.mp4'. Check the log for details.`

I think i put wrong output location? please help

Comment: @mrana The vlc example is for cropping during playback only, not for making a new cropped file.

Comment: Ok, after running this command `vlc input.mp4 --crop=480x500+290+720` the VLC player open and run for sometimes. but after that i can't see any cange on `input.mp4` file?

Comment: I think this needs a clarification; "crop during playback" means we're not getting an output file, only the player shows the cropped result and that's it, and is likely not what OP asked for.

Comment: @Jonny I tried telling him that several times in the comments but apparently I wasn't able to communicate it clearly enough. I'll add a sentence to the answer later today.

Comment: Yes, it took me a while to realize that.

Comment: Using bitstream filter worked perfectly when playing back the new video in mplayer, but would be messed up in both VLC (3.0.9.2) and Kodi (18).

Comment: @Programster Guess I should have tested those. I would have assumed it would have worked in VLC. I'll add a note.

Comment: Could it be possible to do lossless cropping by cropping only on the quantization blocks ? Basically just copy the entire blocks inside the cropped zone and just discard all blocks outside of this zone ?

Comment: The bitstream filter is kind of black magic. I just wanted to say thanks for sharing that.

Answer (score 6):

For some video formats at least, the soft solution based on metadata *should* be possible with FFmpeg as well by using *bitstream* filters from libavcodec, e.g. [`hevc_metadata`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-bitstream-filters.html#hevc_005fmetadata) or [`h264_metadata`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-bitstream-filters.html#h264_005fmetadata).

Unlike filters like [`crop`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop) and `cropdetect`, this does not require decoding. The syntax slightly differs, though, because you can only set the amount of cropping from the four edges, not the target rectangle size. For the OP's 480×270 area at position (200,200) from the top left in a 1920×1080 full HD frame, we get:

- `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -codec copy -bsf:v h264_metadata=crop_left=200:crop_right=1240:crop_top=200:crop_bottom=610 output.mp4`

Since this is codec metadata, this *should* work regardless the container format, i.e. not just in MP4, but in MKV or AVI as well. Alas, I have not tested it myself yet and cannot say anything about support in software and hardware players. (A first simple check failed miserably, though.)

For more detailed info, FFmpeg's documentation refers to sections 7.4.3.2.1 and 7.4.2.1.1 of the H.265 and H.264 specifications respectively, which are freely available from ITU and are basically equivalent:

> - **`frame_cropping_flag`** equal to 1 specifies that the frame cropping offset parameters follow next in the sequence parameter set.
>     frame_cropping_flag equal to 0 specifies that the frame cropping offset parameters are not present.
> - **`frame_crop_left_offset`, `frame_crop_right_offset`, `frame_crop_top_offset`, `frame_crop_bottom_offset`** specify the samples of the pictures in the coded video sequence that are output from the decoding process, in terms of a rectangular
>     region specified in frame coordinates for output.
>     The variables `CropUnitX` and `CropUnitY` are derived as follows:
>
>   – If ChromaArrayType is equal to 0, CropUnitX and CropUnitY are derived as:
>     `CropUnitX = 1`
>     `CropUnitY = 2 − frame_mbs_only_flag`
>     – Otherwise (`ChromaArrayType` is equal to 1, 2, or 3), `CropUnitX` and `CropUnitY` are derived as:
>     `CropUnitX = SubWidthC`
>     `CropUnitY = SubHeightC * ( 2 − frame_mbs_only_flag )`
>
> The frame cropping rectangle contains luma samples with horizontal frame coordinates from
>   `CropUnitX * frame_crop_left_offset to PicWidthInSamplesL − ( CropUnitX * frame_crop_right_offset + 1 )`
>   and vertical frame coordinates from 
>   `CropUnitY * frame_crop_top_offset to ( 16 * FrameHeightInMbs ) −
>   ( CropUnitY * frame_crop_bottom_offset + 1 )`, inclusive.
>
> The value of `frame_crop_left_offset` shall be in the range of 0
>   to `( PicWidthInSamplesL / CropUnitX ) − ( frame_crop_right_offset + 1 )`, inclusive; 
>   and the value of `frame_crop_top_offset` shall be in the range of 0 to `( 16 * FrameHeightInMbs / CropUnitY ) − ( frame_crop_bottom_offset + 1 )`, inclusive.
>
> When `frame_cropping_flag` is equal to 0, the values of `frame_crop_left_offset`, `frame_crop_right_offset`, `frame_crop_top_offset`, and `frame_crop_bottom_offset` shall be inferred to be equal to 0.
>
> When `ChromaArrayType` is not equal to 0, the corresponding specified samples of the two chroma arrays are the samples having frame coordinates `( x / SubWidthC, y / SubHeightC )`, where `( x, y )` are the frame coordinates of the specified luma
>   samples.
>
> For decoded fields, the specified samples of the decoded field are the samples that fall within the rectangle specified in frame coordinates.

Comment: This is a nice solution. It really doesn't reencode the h264 video. I tried this with one of my video files, but it didn't work reliably between different video players. I am using VLC Player and it interprets crop_left and crop_top wrong, the video has been cropped from the right and bottom instead. Then I tried Windows Media Player and there the same video was cropped as intended from top and left. I need to have the video cropped in all players the same way, so I cannot use this option.

Comment: @MarekJ47 VLC is so very buggy, who cares.

Answer (score 3):

At a basic level you cannot make use of a lossy encoding and then expect it to not lose quality when you decode and then encode again. The only way that works is to make use of a lossless codec, for example Quicktime with the Animation codec. This is just a basic truth of digital video production that you cannot work around by just passing command line options to ffmpeg.

Comment: there must be some way, coz i am not compressing the video but cropping it.

Comment: but you are compressing the video. Video can not be modified while in its compressed form. Just like any other compresses content, like a zip file. It must be uncompressed, modified (cropped), then compressed again. Thant being said, you shouldn't lose TOO much quality give an high enough bitrate.

Comment: Masud, why did you ask a question if you were going to ignore the answer? For background information please see: http://www.howtogeek.com/142174/what-lossless-file-formats-are-why-you-shouldnt-convert-lossy-to-lossless/

Comment: @MoDJ sorry i am new in stackoverflow

Comment: Note that this answer talks about "decode and then encode again". OP seems to not know that cropping requires de- and encoding. This is necessary because cropping changes the image data (if you want to drop the unused data).

Comment: You can obviously do a lossless crop even if the compression is lossy, just look at JPEG, mp3, ogg vorbis etc.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible using ffmpeg.

As alternative you can embed your video in a Matroska (.mkv) container and  [set a cropping tag in the file header](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/346278-MKVToolnix-cropping-or-changing-display-width-height), but [it must be supported by your player](https://github.com/mbunkus/mkvtoolnix/wiki/Cropping-ignored).

Reportedly, for H264-encoded videos [H264info](http://www.videohelp.com/software/H264info) can also be used, but i still need to figure out how to use it...

Comment: This should also be possible with FFmpeg bitstream filters, see my answer (which started out as a comment to this one).