# Lossless trim and crop of MJPEG video

Tags: python, ffmpeg, mjpeg

I am working on a project where I need to trim and crop MJPEG videos without any re-encoding. I have working code that accomplishes this by exporting the relevant frames as JPEGs, cropping them individually, and then joining them back together into an MJPEG.

However, this seems quite inefficient and slow. I am looking for pointers how to improve this approach. For example, would it be possible to store the JPEGs in-memory?

```
import ffmpeg
import os
import shutil
import subprocess

def lossless_trim_and_crop(path, output_path, start, end, x, y, width, height, fps):
  # Trim the video in time and export all individual jpeg with ffmpeg + mjpeg2jpeg
  jpeg_folder = os.path.splitext(output_path)[0]
  jpeg_path = os.path.join(jpeg_folder, "frame_%03d.jpg")
  stream = ffmpeg.input(path, ss=start/fps, t=(end-start)/fps)
  stream = ffmpeg.output(stream, jpeg_path, vcodec='copy', **{'bsf:v': 'mjpeg2jpeg'})
  stream.run(quiet=True)
  # Crop all individual jpeg with jpegtran
  for filename in os.listdir(jpeg_folder):
    filepath = os.path.join(jpeg_folder, filename)
    out_filepath = os.path.splitext(filepath)[0] + "_c.jpg"
    subprocess.call(
      "jpegtran -perfect -crop {}x{}+{}+{} -outfile {} {}".format(
        width, height, x, y, out_filepath, filepath), shell=True)
    os.remove(filepath)
  # Join individual jpg back together
  cropped_jpeg_path = os.path.join(jpeg_folder, "frame_%03d_c.jpg")
  stream = ffmpeg.input(cropped_jpeg_path, framerate=fps)
  stream = ffmpeg.output(stream, output_path, vcodec='copy')
  stream.run(quiet=True)
  # Delete jpeg directory
  shutil.rmtree(jpeg_folder)
```

Comment: `ffmpeg` has approximately a billion command line options, and can certainly do cropping.  Have you investigated to see whether its MJPEG cropping will do?

Comment: I am fairly certain that cropping directly via `ffmpeg` would be lossy. I am going off the advice in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33422359/3595278.

Comment: Yes, but that's talking about H.264, which cannot be cropped losslessly.  I'm just saying it's worth a try.

Comment: It does specifically mention MJPEG at the very bottom of the answer. The loss would result from the JPEG decoding and re-encoding done by `ffmpeg`. I guess I could see how much difference this loss makes for my application, but since it is possible I was hoping to make the true lossless approach more efficient.

Comment: You're right, the crop filter would require re-encoding. Your current method is basically what I would do too, except maybe I'd dump the images into `/tmp` and add `-optimize` to `jpegtran` if it wasn't too slow.